# Citrix XenDesktop - WSUS - Port 80 Conflict IIS Default Web Site

Tags: iis-7, citrix, wsus, port-80, xendesktop

I've got my XenDesktop setup on a 2k8 server running on the Default Site under IIS. I just installed WSUS 3.0 and and was able to put the admin access on it's own website, but the self_update still runs on port 80. Which causes my citrix web access to break and wsus admin to break as well.

I think that WSUS selfupdate has to run on port 80? I'm not sure if it can be moved. I've been looking for an answer for 4 hours.

Comment: How about installing WSUS on another server?

Comment: I don't have another server.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going on here:
http://www.conetrix.com/Blog/post/Internal-Server-Errors-on-64-bit-WSUS-With-Other-32-bit-Websites-in-IIS.aspx